# Read XML by its tag name

Tags: c#, xml

I Have XML from Services Respond , here's the sample :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns4:loginResponse xmlns="http://www.website.com/IncTypes" xmlns:ns2="http://yyy.website.com/Security" xmlns:ns3="http://yyy.incognito.com/Service" xmlns:ns4="http:/yyy.website.com/wsdl/Security">
            <ns2:errorCode>
                <hasError>true</hasError>
                <status>STATUS_ERROR</status>
                <problemCode>-1</problemCode>
                <problemMessage>Service Provider 
       not known</problemMessage>
                <extendedInformation>Service Provider 
       not known</extendedInformation>
            </ns2:errorCode>
        </ns4:loginResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I just want to get the value of this Tag

```
                    <hasError>true</hasError>
                    <status>STATUS_ERROR</status>
                    <problemCode>-1</problemCode>
                    <problemMessage>Service Provider
```

and here's my C# Code:

```
 foreach (XmlNode node in loginresp.DocumentElement)
            {
                if (node.FirstChild.FirstChild.HasChildNodes == true)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode y in node.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        HasError = y.InnerXml;
                        status= y.InnerXml;
                    }
                }
            }
```

but it gives me either `HasError` and `ErroCode` the same value of `<ns2:errorCode>` which is `<extendedInformation>Service Provider  not known</extendedInformation>` how could I get    `<hasError>true</hasError>`    `<status>STATUS_ERROR</status>` value only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use LINQ-to-XML as also suggested by @noMad17. What makes it not very trivial is, your xml has namespaces. Hence we need to define `XNamespace`s to be used to match element names :

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.website.com/IncTypes";
XNamespace ns2 = "http://yyy.website.com/Security";
var loginresp = XDocument.Parse("xml string here");
//get <ns2:errorCode> element
var errorCode = loginresp.Descendants(ns2 + "errorCode").FirstOrDefault();
if(errorCode != null)
{
    //get <hasError> element under <ns2:errorCode>
    var hasError = (string)errorCode.Element(ns + "hasError");
    //get <status> element under <ns2:errorCode>
    var status = (string)errorCode.Element(ns + "status");
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you , works properly, yes I've tried about the xml.linq but keep getting error, and I forgot to mention the namespace to check the element.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use [System.Xml.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
XElement elem = xDocument.Descendants("hasErrors").FirstOrDefault();
```

This would give you the tag you wanted.